# Eavesdrop on UNIX socket connection without root

Tags: sockets, security, unix

Let's say a server is running and listening on `/var/run/some-socket.sock`. And `/var/run/some-socket.sock` has owner `root` and group `root`.

Is it possible for program `B` that does not run under `root` to eavesdrop on writes/reads from program `A` to the socket? How can I prevent program `B` from eavesdropping on connection from `A`?

Comment: 1) "is it possible ...to eavesdrop" yes chmod 666 the socket 2) encrypt the traffic using keys that are known to the server and to program A but not program B

Comment: 1) so if I chmod 622 (rw/w/w) and set the owner of the socket to the server, no one else apart from root will be able to eavesdrop, right? 2) ok

Comment: You cannot eavesdrop Unix domain sockets just by reading a `.sock` file. In fact, unless you MITM the connection, you can't eavesdrop on Unix domain sockets period. See [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106785/how-to-listen-to-nginx-writes-to-a-file-socket), [this article](http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html), [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.programmer/Ffn3PJzqkW4), and [this email thread](http://linux-list.lists2.linuxjournal.narkive.com/aIQH4RIs/sll-eavesdropping-unix-sockets)

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

Sockets aren't files, and `.sock` files aren't sockets. Sockets are in-memory constructs that can be accessed by two processes that have established a connection. Each process can read and write to the socket construct as if it were a file, and so communicate. This socket "file" only exists as an abstraction in memory; it is never written to disk.

However, a process wishing to open a socket to another program needs some way of communicating with the other program so they can establish a socket and communicate. Naturally, this poses something of a problem. `.sock` files are one way around this problem. They represent an address that a process, in this case `A`, is listening on. If another process, like `B`, attempts to open a socket to the `.sock` file, the operating system will pass a connection request to `A`. If `A` is actually listening to that address, and accepts the connection, then `A` and `B` can set up a socket connection and communicate.

Of course, if the socket represents a connection to an external network, i.e. an internet connection, then it is possible to eavesdrop on what is being sent over the interface used for that connection. Wireshark and tcpdump can do this.